# static_cast does compile with no errors?

Tags: c++, class

If I have two classes:

**1)** Employee

**2)** Engineer which is **derived** from Employee

**3)** Manager which is **derived** from Employee

I was told (and tried myself) that the following doesn't compile:

```
Employee employee("John Smith");
Engineer* ptr2 = &employee; // error
```

Since an Employee is not an Engineer for sure.

But why the following runs normal:

```
Manager* m = ...;
Employee* emp = m;
Manager* m1 = static_cast<Manager*>(emp);//Ok
```

why I'm allowed now to cast Employee into Manager?

Comment: _"an Employee isn't an Engineer and an Engineer isn't an Employee (They can be called brother)"_ That's wrong. An Engineer is an Employee. An Engineer and a Manager are brothers. You can write `Engineer engineer; Employee *ptr = &engineer;`. You can implicitly upcast but you can't implicitly downcast. A downcast is narrowing. You have to use static_cast or dynamic_cast

Comment: Here are the rules for [static_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) and here are the rules for [dynamic_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)

Comment: @ThomasSablik corrected that, please read it again

Comment: Did you read the rules in my link? It's all described there.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I read it but what point are you referring to, I don't see something similar....

Comment: You skipped point 2. You also skipped the example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Manager* m = ...;
> Employee* emp = m;
> ```

This performs an [implicit cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Pointer_conversions) from `Manager*` to `Employee*`. This is allowed because a pointer to a derived class type can be **implicitly** converted to a pointer to its base class. (There are some caveats, none of which apply in your case. So I choose to stick to the simple version.) It's allowed to be implicit because the result is guaranteed to be as valid as the starting point.

> ```
> Manager* m1 = static_cast<Manager*>(emp);//Ok
> ```

This performs a [static cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast#Explanation) from `Employee*` to `Manager*`. This is allowed because a pointer to a base class can be **explicitly** converted to a pointer to a derived class (known as a downcast). **This static cast may only be used safely if the object in question is actually the derived class.** You are allowed to shoot yourself in the foot when you choose to explicitly downcast with a `static_cast`. (The safe version of a downcast is provided by `dynamic_cast`.)

Comment: Thanks, but if it's dangerous why they allowed it in c++ at first?

Comment: @smith It's not dangerous if you know what you do and a dynamic_cast is more expensive and not always possible. You can disable RTTI to improve the performance

Comment: Because sometimes it's the right thing to so and amazingly fast. C++ often allows a programmer to risk <expletive deleted>ing up in the name of speed.

Comment: @smith Why would it not be allowed? C++ has no policy banning dangerous practices. If you meant to ask if there is a use-case, yes there is. A `static_cast` is faster than a `dynamic_cast`, so if safety can be guaranteed by other means, the overhead of `dynamic_cast` is not needed.